# How to draw borders of different DIV sections?

Tags: html, css, border

How can I draw boxes of div sections without using the table border element? So far, my website has been like this:

[image: https://imageshack.com/i/pbc7BDqmp]

But for every piece of line, I have to write a  element, which is not my aim actually. I just want a border without having to use this  element.

Comment: Can you add code to your question?

Comment: Are you asking how to have columns without tables?

Comment: No, I meant without the <td> element, I just want a box border with specified length(for example 100px height and 50px wide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to know exactly what you want without an example of your code, but see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b68vD/). Is that what you're looking for? Similar to kr neki res's answer, but uses classes instead, as then this border isn't applied to all of your divs, and you can pick and choose which divs you want to add the border to by setting their class to the same thing. Code for this JSFiddle:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">I'm in a box</div>
<div class="box">I'm in a box2</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

You can also have the boxes float beside each other like in this other [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b68vD/1/), by adding this to your CSS:

CSS:

```
float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for div, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px 40px; 
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>Here in your "div" you will see border.</div>

</body>
</html>
```